# Creating boxplots for visualisation in R using a function

Tags: r, function, visualization

I wrote a code to get boxplots for visualisation in R. The code is running but I am not getting any boxplots. Can you please help identify where I went wrong.

```
create_boxplots <- function(x, y){
  ggplot(data = forest_fires) +
  aes_string(x = x, y = y) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"))
}

    x_var_month <- names(forest_fires)[3]
    y_var <- names(forest_fires)[5:12]
    month_box <- map2(x_var_month, y_var, create_boxplots)
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Try to remove unnecessary variables, and create a reproducible error with simplest code possible so that others can try and replicate the same error, and help you. All the best.

Comment: To add to the above, it would be even better if you could include a  [reproducible data example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to go along with that [reproducibly code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is ok, just that when you call ggplot inside a function, you return the object and it is stored in a list. You need to print it. For example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)
library(gridExtra)

create_boxplots <- function(x, y){
  ggplot(data = forest_fires) +
  aes_string(x = x, y = y) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"))
}

forest_fires = data.frame(matrix(runif(1300),ncol=13))
forest_fires[,3] = factor(sample(1:12,nrow(forest_fires),replace=TRUE))

    x_var_month <- names(forest_fires)[3]
    y_var <- names(forest_fires)[5:12]
    month_box <- map2(x_var_month, y_var, create_boxplots)
```

This shows you the plot for `y_var[1]`

```
month_box[[1]]
#or print(month_box[[1]])
```

[image]

To get everything in 1 plot do:

```
grid.arrange(grobs=month_box)
```

[image]